# how to change page title in angular router

Tags: angular

I would like to change the main title of my application every time I change my route like My first application - Dashboard or My first application - Statistic

Here is my code, I use Material UI :

defaut.component.html:

```
<div>
    <mat-toolbar>
        <button mat-icon-button *ngIf="sidenav.mode === 'over'" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
            <mat-icon *ngIf="!sidenav.opened">
                menu
            </mat-icon>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="sidenav.opened">
                close
            </mat-icon>
        </button>
        <img class="logo" src=".." alt="logo" />
        <h1 class="title">My first application - </h1>  // Title 
    </mat-toolbar>

    <mat-sidenav-container>
        <mat-sidenav #sidenav="matSidenav">
            <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
        </mat-sidenav>
        <mat-sidenav-content>
            <div class="main">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </mat-sidenav-content>
    </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

defaut.component.ts:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default',
  templateUrl: './default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.component.css']
})

export class DefaultComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(MatSidenav)
  sidenav!: MatSidenav;

  constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.observer.observe(['(max-width:959px)']).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.matches) {
        this.sidenav.mode = 'over';
        this.sidenav.close()
      }
      else {
        this.sidenav.mode = 'side';
        this.sidenav.open()
      }
    })
  }

}
```

sidebar.component.html:

```
<div class="navbar">

    <h2>Menu</h2>

        <div class="menu-item">
            <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/app/dashboard" routerLinkActive="active" style="text-decoration:none">
                <span>Dashboard</span>
            </button>
            <button mat-button class="menu-button" routerLink="/app/statistic" routerLinkActive="active" style="text-decoration:none">
                <span>Statistic</span>
            </button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While the answer below is certainly well written... what title do you actually want to change? The actual title of the page tab - or  `<h1 class="title">My first application - </h1>`?

Comment: I would like to complete the title according to the roads. For example with React, I use const title = location.pathname === '/app/dashboard' ? 'Dashboard' : location.pathname === '/app/statistics' ? 'Statistics' and <h1>My first app - ${title}</h1>

Answer (score 5):

#### For Angular version 14 and above

Angular now permits you [to set the page title with routing](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-the-page-title).

So where you configure the RouterModule with the routes array, you can add a title to a given route, or configure a [TitleStrategy](https://angular.io/api/router/TitleStrategy):

```
{ path: 'default', component: DefaultComponent, title: 'Default' }
```

#### For Angular Versions below 14

Use the [Title service](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title).

A common way to do this is to save the current title on component load, set your own title, then in the `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle callback, you set back the previous title.

So in your component TypeScript file, you could have something like:

```
import { BreakpointObserver } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-default',
  templateUrl: './default.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./default.component.css']
})
export class DefaultComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(MatSidenav)
  sidenav!: MatSidenav;
  oldTitle: string;

  constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver, private title: Title) {
    this.oldTitle = this.title.getTitle();
    this.title.setTitle('New Title Here');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.observer.observe(['(max-width:959px)']).subscribe((res) => {
      if (res.matches) {
        this.sidenav.mode = 'over';
        this.sidenav.close();
      } else {
        this.sidenav.mode = 'side';
        this.sidenav.open();
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.title.setTitle(this.oldTitle);
  }
}
```

Comment: That Route approach is very handy

Answer (score 1):

There's an Angular service that updates the title - you can use it it the main page components

- https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Title

Answer (score 0):

1. Import the below in the required component
   import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser;
2. In constructor initialise the title variable
   constructor(private titleService:Title) {
    }

Update the title with this
3) ngOnInit() {

this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);

[Click here for demo](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/set-page-title-using-title-service-angular-example/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).